# Sql insert or update

Tags: c#, sql, asp-classic, sql-server-ce

I need to rapidly write code to insert/update SQL data. In classic ASP/VBScript I could do that like below:

```
  Set rs = Server.CreateObject("adodb.Recordset")
  sql = "SELECT * FROM _table WHERE id=" & id 
  rs.Open sql, cn, 1, 3 

  If rs.recordcount = 0 Then 
    rs.AddNew 
  End If 

  rs("data") = data

  rs.Update 
  rs.Close
```

What could be the nearest C# port of this code snippet? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully this gets you started.  Make a reference to the ADODB class:

```
ADODB.Connection cn = new ADODB.Connection();
cn.Open("Provider=etc...", null, null, 0);
ADODB.Recordset rs = new ADODB.Recordset();

String sql = "SELECT * FROM _table WHERE id=" & id;
rs.Open(sql, cn, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenKeyset, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic, -1);

if (rs.RecordCount == 0)
  rs.AddNew;

rs("data") = data;
rs.Update();
rs.Close();
cn.Close();
```

Comment: This is indeed the "nearest C# port" of the OP's code. But it is an abomination to use this in .NET

Comment: @Jamiec I agree, but for converting existing code, it helps bridge the technology to using SQL or OLEDB libraries.

Comment: I'll use your answer, for now. Later, I'll need to use a pure .NET way.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming MS-SQL:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Connection String"))
using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO MyTable (Name, Age) VALUES (@name, @age)", conn))
{    
    conn.Open();

    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "Adam");
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", 25);

    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Connection string obviously needs fleshing out, and the parameterised SQL needs confirming, but this is the start of what you need.

You don't need to worry about closing as the `using` statement does this for you.

**Update:** not knowing classic ASP very well, I should clarify that this code only does an insert and not an update, if you need to do an update, change the SQL to use the update syntax.

Comment: Realised when I saw the rs("data") =, I immediately saw the "SELECT" and thought the question title was wrong to be honest.